# How do I know when 2 absolute html element stack on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

A little background on my current project:
I'm building the calendar scheduler.

I have a structure as below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.title {
  border: 1px #333 solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
.task {
  margin-top: 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.eachTask {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px #333 solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.task1 {
  left: 100px;
}

.task2 {
  left: 300px;
}

.task3 {
  left: 500px;
}

.task4 {
  left: 500px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="label">
    <div class="title">Monday</div>
    <div class="title">Tuesday</div>
    <div class="title">Wednesday</div>
    <div class="title">Thursday</div>
    <div class="title">Friday</div>
    <div class="title">Saturday</div>
    <div class="title">Sunday</div>
  </div>

  <div class="task">
    <div class="eachTask task1">Task1</div>
    <div class="eachTask task2">Task2</div>
    <div class="eachTask task3">Task3</div>
    <div class="eachTask task4">Task4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I put the top position for the Task4 to appear below Task 3. Otherwise, it will stack on top of eachother.
Is there any way to know if the element is overlapping or stacking so that I can align it below.

I have a list of tasks, every task will be displayed on the same line, is there any way to know that each of them has the same position or stacking on top of each other so that I can set the top position to put it below. (Note: I have control the width of each task and the left position).

I have an idea about looping all the task, For each task I will compare the left and the width value with all the other one. If one of them is stacking I will insert the top position. but as far as I concern It will be a nested loop.

Thank you
http://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-cerf-jeipz?file=/index.html:0-1525

Edit: I put one more case here to get my idea
Please consider it like a Gant Chart

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-star-rvcpe?file=/index.html

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using `position: absolute;` ?

Comment: My calendar combines the Drag and Resize feature, so It should be displayed on the same line, I guess. For example, I can resize task 1 expand Tuesday and Wednesday (1 div - element)

Comment: Can't you have an invisible div under each day and just append each task in that div? It will automatically list tasks vertically as long as you have a set width for the div.

Comment: Thanks, David, I'm thinking of it but putting each div bellow each day does not suit my structure. For example, I have a Resize feature and expand 1 task for many days in a row, so it should not display in one column but multiples columns.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to add a class to each task representing the day of the week? If so you can kind of hack to together with js sort of by adding an increasing `margin-top` to each progressive task.  Take a look at what I did here:

```js
var marginsat=-40;
$(".saturday").each(function(){
  $(this).css("margin-top",marginsat+=40)
})

var margintues=-40;
$(".tuesday").each(function(){
  $(this).css("margin-top",margintues+=40)
})

var marginth=-40;
$(".thursday").each(function(){
  $(this).css("margin-top",marginth+=40)
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.title {
  border: 1px #333 solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
.task {
  margin-top: 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.eachTask {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px #333 solid;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.task1 {
  left: 100px;
}

.task2 {
  left: 300px;
}

.task3 {
  left: 500px;
}

.task4 {
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="label">
    <div class="title">Monday</div>
    <div class="title">Tuesday</div>
    <div class="title">Wednesday</div>
    <div class="title">Thursday</div>
    <div class="title">Friday</div>
    <div class="title">Saturday</div>
    <div class="title">Sunday</div>
  </div>

  <div class="task">
    <div class="eachTask task1 tuesday">Task1</div>
    <div class="eachTask task2 thursday">Task2</div>
    <div class="eachTask task3 saturday">Task3</div>
    <div class="eachTask task4 saturday">Task4</div>
    <div class="eachTask task4 saturday">Task5</div>
    <div class="eachTask task4 saturday">Task6</div>
    <div class="eachTask task1 tuesday">Task7</div>
    <div class="eachTask task2 thursday">Task8</div>
    <div class="eachTask task1 tuesday">Task9</div>
    <div class="eachTask task2 thursday">Task10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, John, I look at your code but seems like it not match my structure. Please see this link to get the idea. I want if the task is stacking on each other, It will be automatically adding a top position ( I can get the width and the left position of eachtask) . https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-star-rvcpe?file=/index.html